# Erro install paramiko on raspberrypi

Tags: raspberry-pi, importerror, paramiko

When I install paramiko on raspberypi , have this problem:

```
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to upgrade your `libc6` package?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

From: [How to fix “/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found”?](https://superuser.com/questions/537683/how-to-fix-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found)

> That means the program was compiled against glibc version 2.14, and it requires that version to run, but your system has an older version installed. You'll need to either recompile the program against the version of glibc that's on your system, or install a newer version of glibc (the "libc6" package in Debian).

Comment: Thanks.

I run cmd you said ,and the os show me:"
libc6 is already the newest version (2.24-11+deb9u4)."

I dealt with the problem by install paramiko version 1.x.x(now version is 2.x.x).Because the lower version is dependency on the lower GLIBC_X.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I solve the problem by the root.Upgrade Raspbian Stretch to Raspbian Buster.
https://pimylifeup.com/upgrade-raspbian-stretch-to-raspbian-buster/